# How to use two tab bars (and view pager) in one Activity?

Tags: android, view, tabs, android-viewpager, tabbar

I'm using this lib for the tab bars : [link](https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout)
According the picture I use it and it works but there is a problem that I should use a view pager in another view pager and it makes some problems such as what you see in the picture.
How can I solve it?

[A Screen shot from my app and the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qd9RI.jpg)

edit : Here is my code

```
MainActivity.js


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    FragmentPagerItemAdapter adapter = new FragmentPagerItemAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager(), FragmentPagerItems.with(this)
            .add("1111", PageFragment.class)
            .add("222", PageFragment.class)
            .add("33333", PageFragment.class)
            .add("444", PageFragment.class)
            .create());

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    SmartTabLayout viewPagerTab = (SmartTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.viewpagertab);
    viewPagerTab.setViewPager(viewPager);
}
```

}

And this code is for the first tab bar

```
PageFragment.js

public class PageFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_demo, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        int position = FragmentPagerItem.getPosition(getArguments());
        FragmentPagerItemAdapter adapter = new FragmentPagerItemAdapter(
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), FragmentPagerItems.with(getActivity())
                .add("One", TestFragment.class)
                .add("Two", TestFragment.class)
                .add("Three", TestFragment.class)
                .add("Four", TestFragment.class)
                .add("Five", TestFragment.class)
                .add("Six", TestFragment.class)

                .create());

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager2);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        SmartTabLayout viewPagerTab = (SmartTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpagertab2);
        viewPagerTab.setViewPager(viewPager);
    }
}
```

And here is code for fragment of second tab bar

```
TestFragment.js

public class TestFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);
    }

    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code for the activity please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem solved by using `getChildFragmentManager()` class instead of

```
 getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
```

in **PageFragment.js** file

Answer (score 0):

You are probably going to be down-voted since you have made no effort in resolving this on your own or you don't have your findings!

However, I have recently implemented this and it worked fine for my case. 
It has two tabs (as two fragments) in one single activity.

The code goes below.

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TabLayout.Tab Tab1,Tab2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    Tab1 = tabLayout.newTab().setText("Monthly Expenses");
    Tab2 = tabLayout.newTab().setText("Daily Expenses");

    tabLayout.addTab(Tab1);
    tabLayout.addTab(Tab2);
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

**PagerAdapter.java :**

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{
int NumOfTabs;
public PagerAdapter (FragmentManager fm, int NumberOfTabs)
{
    super(fm);
    this.NumOfTabs = NumberOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position)
{
    switch (position)
    {
        case 0:
            TabFragment1 tab1 = new TabFragment1();
            return tab1;

        case 1:
            TabFragment2 tab2 = new TabFragment2();
            return tab2;

        default:
            return null;
    }
}

public int getCount()
{
    return NumOfTabs;
}
}
```

**TabFragment1.java :**

```
public class TabFragment1 extends Fragment{
FloatingActionButton fab;
MyBaseAdapter baseAdapter;
static ArrayList<ListRowItem> listitem = new ArrayList<>();
ListView listView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_1, container, false);
}
}
```

**TabFragment2.java :**

```
public class TabFragment2 extends Fragment{
FloatingActionButton fab;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_2, container, false);
}
}
```

Hope this is what you are looking for!

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think you did not realize what I want. I want two tab bars, not two tabs ! like the image that I uploaded above.